# Do repeated integrals vanish?

Tags: calculus, integration

I define repeated integrals similar to [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html), for more details see there.

$D^{-n}f(x) = \int \cdots \int_0^x f(t) dt\cdots dt=\int_0^x \frac{f(t)(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt$

As far as I see this implies, that $D^{-n}f(x)$ converges to $0$ on $[0,1]$, as we have (could be applied to every interval):

$|D^{-n}f(x)|<\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x |f(t)|dt<\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt<\frac{max(|f(t)|)}{(n-1)!}$

However there are (many) functions that do not converge to zero, independent of how often we integrate them ($e^x, sin(x), cos(x)$ and variations of these).

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate $e^x$ by your method, you do **not** get $e^x$, you do get
$e^x-1$. Integrating again, you get $e^x-1-x$, then $e^x-1-x-x^2/2$, etc. Now can you see why these converge to zero?

Comment: Yes makes sense. Do you also have an "intuitive" explanation why they vanish? It still doesn't really make sense to me (or alternatively why we should expect to that the tailor expansion will be subtracted)?